# In power bi how to convert number to string

Tags: ms-office, powerbi

In my data table i have column category types (1, 2 , 3). I want to change them to say 1 = hot desk, 2 = fix desk, 3 = private company. how to do it? I'm oky to create new column if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways of doing this.

One way is to create a second table, a lookup table, with two columns [ID] and [Text]. The ID column has a single row for each of your category types (1, 2, 3) and the second column contains the corresponding string value. Then you create a 1:* relationship between category type column and ID column. In a visual you can then build the visual with the information from the table containing the category type column and the string value from the new lookup table.

A second way is creating a calculated column in the original table using an IF or SWITCH statement.

Which solution is the best for you depends on how many different category types and how many rows of data you have in the data table. intuitively I would say that the lookup table option is better from a resource usage.

Cheers,

Oscar

Comment: sry i was out of office yesterday. so didn't have time to check.

Answer (score 0):

Oscars solution should work. You could also create a Conditional Column in Power Query.
Add Column Tab > General Group > Conditional Column.

Comment: This is true. Though I suggested the Power BI solution since the computational engine in Power BI (VertiPaq) has been shown (in Monte Carlo examples) to be much faster than the Power Query engine [link](https://www.oraylis.de/blog/monte-carlo-simulation-with-dax-and-power-query) Cheers, Oscar